# transport problem between classes - identify (optimise) flow of individual entities

Tags: r, optimization, transport

I have a large table of cells (rows) that belong to a certain class. In a next step, the distribution of classes has to change and I want to identify which cells need to be moved between classes minimising the costs that occur by moving cells between classes.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(transport)

set.seed(19)

## classes: 1 - 5
## overall cost matrix for transport
costs <- matrix(expand_grid(a = 1:5, b = 1:5) %>% mutate(cost = abs(b - a)) %>% 
    pull(cost), ncol = 5, nrow =5)

## dataset with initial classes and individual transport costs into other classes
dat   <- tibble(class = sample(rep(1:5, each = 1000), 200)) %>% 
    bind_cols(t(apply(., 1, function(x) abs(x - 1:5)*runif(5))) %>% 
    as_tibble() %>% setNames(paste0("cl", 1:5)))
```

The dataset with initial classes and costs to move the row into the other classes (cl1-5).

```
head(dat)
# A tibble: 6 × 6
  class   cl1   cl2   cl3   cl4   cl5
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2 0.298 0     0.353 1.52  2.57 
2     5 0.129 1.12  0.986 0.867 0    
3     3 0.940 0.446 0     0.811 0.670
4     5 0.759 2.82  1.65  0.582 0    
5     3 1.39  0.134 0     0.438 1.39 
6     5 2.89  0.492 0.870 0.954 0
```

I first solved the mass transport problem, identifying the number of cells that need to be moved from a certain class into another:

```
## mass distribution of classes
prob0 <- dat %>% group_by(class) %>% summarise(p = n()/nrow(dat))

## new distribution of classes
prob1 <- tibble(class = sample(rep(1:5, each = 1000), 200)) %>% 
   group_by(class) %>% summarise(p = n()/nrow(dat))

## Solving transport problem of masses
trans <- transport(prob0$p, prob1$p, costs) %>% filter(from!=to) %>%
    left_join(dat %>% group_by(class) %>% 
    summarise(rows = n()), by = join_by("from"=="class")) %>%
    mutate(nrRows = round(rows*mass,0))
```

```
trans
  from to mass rows nrRows
1    1  4 0.03   39      1
2    3  4 0.06   46      3
3    5  4 0.04   48      2
```

With this, I know how many cells should be moved from the initial class into a new class.

QUESTION: What method can I use to efficiently find the best rows to move according to the costs (minimisation costs for all changes of classes) that occur by moving the row?

I wonder of that problem can be solved directly without calculating the mass flow between classes, i.e. moving rows directly minimising the costs until the desired class distribution is achieved?

Comment: Have you looked at approaching it as an integer programming problem?

Comment: Interesting - I have not, but will look into it. Maybe you have a way/pipeline to get me started?

Comment: This can certainly be approached as an ILP (Integer Linear Program).  it isn't clear from the info you have provided what "mass flow" is all about.  You have a group of N objects in M classes that need to be rearranged.  You have a cost for each possible move.  What is the driver here for "mass transport"?  Do these objects have some mass and there are limits on classes or ???  That would form a constraint in your ILP with minimizing cost as the objective.  Editing your code with some clarity on that constraint would help

Comment: Maybe a more simple explanation: I have the initial dataset where each row is assigned to a class. Each row also has a cost value for moving the class into another class. The class distribution (number of rows for each class) has to change to match a given new distribution (here, I used the transport function to identify how many rows of each class has to move into another class). The solution I am seeking would identify the rows that need to be changed (the class value) to achieve the new distribution and minimise the costs that occur by changing the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned you can model it as binary transportation problem where sum of each row must be 1 and sum of each column #rows * wanted distribution.

```
m <- as.matrix(dat[,-1])
p0 <- prob1[["p"]]

res <- lpSolve::lp.transport(
  cost.mat = m,
  direction = "min",
  row.signs = rep("==", nrow(m)),
  row.rhs = rep(1, nrow(dat)),
  col.signs = rep("==", ncol(m)),
  col.rhs = nrow(dat) * p0
)

res[["objval"]] # cost of changes

new_groups <- apply(res[["solution"]], 1, function(x) which(x == 1)) # new group for each row

table(dat[["class"]], new_groups) # change matrix

change_rows <- which(new_groups != dat[["class"]])
if(length(change_rows) > 0)
  changes <- data.frame(
    row = change_rows,
    old_group = dat[["class"]][change_rows],
    new_group = new_groups[change_rows]
  )
```

This obviously wont work if it is impossible to fit new distribution - `nrow(dat) * p0` must be integer vector. In other cases you can use `mco::nsga2` to minimize cost of group change and distribution error.

Comment: Great thanks - that's a very good start I can use and adjust for my needs!